# return array to view doesnt work

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have an array with some sorted numbers in it. the array is just like i want it, so i returned it to my view. now i wanted to get in my view ( html ) the output of the array and php said : htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

thats my first problem.. the seccond problem is, i want the output in my array among one another..

like :

```
number
number
number
number 
.....
```

but its like : `number number number number` in the output..

i really need this for my project and i have everthing i need.. just the output isnt well formatted

here is my code in the controller :

```
$mb_bytes = array();
        foreach ($topTenIp as $val) {
            $bytes_ips[$val] = shell_exec("grep $val /path/file | awk '{print $10}'");
            $add = array_sum(explode("\n", $bytes_ips[$val]));
            $add = $add / 1024 / 1024;
            $add = round($add, 2);
            array_push($mb_bytes, $add);
        }
        if($mb_bytes)
            arsort($mb_bytes);
```

in $mb_bytes are the numbers i want  among one another

and here my html:

```
@foreach($topTenIp as $ip[$i])
   <tr>
       <th>{{ $ip[$i] }}</th>
       <th>{{ here should be the variable mb_bytes }}</th>    
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

passing variable to the view:

```
return view('/domains/data', [
    'mb_bytes' => $mb_bytes,
    'topTenIp' => $topTenIp,
]);
```

I asked this a bit ago and got great help with but it still doesnt want work..

i hope i have a bit more luck today :D

Comment: I don't see you are passing your array from the controller to the view. Where is the rest of the controller code? And would be also helpful if you post here which error  'Laravel'  gives you.

Comment: laravel gives me exactly this error code: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given - it means the mb_byte variable :) -- i updatet the question how i'm passing the array to the view :) ---- the other part of the code isnt needet cause there lots of other random stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated to support sorted array*

First, you somehow have to structure your data so that the results from your loop belong to an IP address. If you don't, your arrays will be in different orders if you sort one of them.
You can add both IPs and bytes to a two dimensional, associative array and sort on that:

```
$ipsWithBytes = [];

foreach ($topTenIp as $val) 
{
    $execResult = shell_exec("grep $val /path/file | awk '{print $10}'");
    $add = array_sum(explode("\n", $execResult));
    $add = $add / 1024 / 1024;
    $add = round($add, 2);

    $ipsWithBytes[] = [  // use the [] notation instead of array_push()
        'ip' => $val,
        'bytes' => $add,
    ];
}

uasort($ipsWithBytes, function($a, $b) { // sort the array descending
    if ($a['bytes'] == $b['bytes'])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    elseif ($a['bytes'] < $b['bytes'])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
});

return view('my_view', compact('ipsWithBytes'));
```

Note that when using PHP 7, you can use the new spaceship operator for sorting the array:

```
uasort($ipsWithBytes, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['bytes'] <=> $a['bytes']; // $b first, so it sorts descending
});
```

Finally, your blade should look like this:

```
@foreach($ipsWithBytes as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $item['ip'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item['bytes'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

To clarify what the htmlentities error means:

The double curly brackets in blade get compiled to `<?php echo htmlentities($var); ?>`. htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be of type string, but in your case, `$var` was of type array.

Comment: LOL it works ! holy mother... i was trying this so much and it havent worked xD ..... big thanks to you :)

Comment: the mb_bytes are the same lenght like the IP variable.. but i dont understand why its not sorted anymore :o if i print_r the variable in the controller its sorted.. but in the view it isnt anymore.. maybe you see why?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that you sort $mb_bytes :P This is a problem, because in your case, the values in $mb_bytes don't belong to their IP anymore after sorting. I will update my answer in a minute which covers that.

Comment: but the IP are sorted too :o

Comment: anyways.. i will try some things too.. if i cant make it, i hope to see you have edited your answer :) i'm very grateful, for your help :D

Comment: no this havent worked :o the output is just 10 times  " 0 "

Comment: Note that i have introduced a new variable called `$execResult` in the foreach loop. Check if you have updated to this variable. Also, whats the output of `var_dump($add)` if you place it just below `$add = round($add, 2);` ?

Comment: the result of add before round.... is 10 times " 0 " :o and yes i noticed the new variable :)

Comment: What is the value of `$execResult` after `shell_exec()`?

Comment: oh... now it works perfect.. my mistake was that i havent changed /path/file in the orginal path and file name.. my mistake sorry xD

Comment: where can i put a arsort to change the datas? now its von min to max.. i need it from max to min :)

Comment: i think i havent can make it like you... man i need to learn more pvp :o :3

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. In the sort function, the comparison has to be: `$a['bytes'] < $b['bytes']`

Comment: perfect ! i'm very gratefull :) youre awesome :3